# Flask: CSS and JS do not load in a kubernetes POD

Tags: python, css, templates, flask, kubernetes

When I host a Flask application in Docker on my PC, the CSS and JS are read correctly from a template and HTML view formatted.
When I host the same application in Kubernetes POD, it does not read CSS and JS.

In a snapshot below you can see a result.
[image: example of CSS and JS not loading]
Below please find a file structure of the app.
Views index.html and upload.html are extending public/templates/public_template.html which consists of imports of CSS and JS libraries.

Could you please tell what could be the reason? Could the required file structure be different between kubectl and Docker?

```
C:.
|   .gitignore
|   Dockerfile
|   upload_app-deploy.yaml
|   run.py
|
\---app
    |   app.py
    |   requirements.txt
    |   __init__.py
    |
    +---static
    |   +---css
    |   |       bootstrap.min.css
    |   |       style.css
    |   |
    |   +---img
    |   |       flask.png
    |   |
    |   \---js
    |           app.js
    |           bootstrap.bundle.min.js
    |           jquery.slim.min.js
    |
    \---templates
        +---admin
        |   \---templates
        \---public
            |   index.html
            |   upload.html
            |
            \---templates
                    public_template.html
```

Error in the browser:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
jquery.slim.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
(index):1 Refused to apply style from 'https://ais-bt-services.asml.com/static/css/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
app.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
(index):1 Refused to apply style from 'https://ais-bt-services.asml.com/static/css/bootstrap.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

[image: browser errors in kubernetes 1]
[image: browser errors in kubernetes 2]

Dockerfile:

```
# Python 3 running on Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)(ATM) (amd64)
FROM XXX/docker/python:3

# Fill directories
COPY . /app

# Switch default directory so f.e. you don't have to provide a full pwd of req.txt
WORKDIR /app/app

# Install python packages with fixed versions
RUN pip install --force-reinstall -r requirements.txt

# Execute an app: listener and handler
CMD ["python", "/app/app/app.py"]
```

Below please find permissions to the catalogues, they seem OK to me, directories to 775 and files to 664 and the root user. Could it be that a user is different once running in Kubernetes? Or maybe any other ideas?
[image: PERMISSIONS]

Comment: How are you running it in the two environments?  In what way doesn't it load – do you get some sort of error in the browser developer console?  If I had this file structure on my local disk, how could I reproduce the problem?

Comment: In a local Docker I run it by: `docker run -p PORT:PORT my-upload-app` from a C: folder and in a Kubernetes ready docker image is pulled from ArtiFactory and put into the Kubernetes by `kubectl apply -f upload_app-deploy.yaml`. The problem could be reproduced by running flask app using CSS and JS libraries locally or in a local Docker like in https://pythonise.com/feed/flask/flask-uploading-files and then try to put the same in a Kubernetes. It stops working. When I try to red logs from `kubectl -n namespace-dt logs upload-app-deploy-123`, there are no errors. Will check brows. errors. Merci.

Comment: The functionality works OK. Only the display is different - basic. To me it seems like public_template.html which is used as a 'exteds from' in index and upload.html does not work properly. It pulls libraries from CSS and JS folders.

Comment: Seems like there is a browser error while reading CSS and JS files, could you please tell what could be a probable cause?

Comment: Can you post your dockerfile?

Comment: sure, thank you for stopping by, Dockerfile added! It goes to the directory of css and JS libraries but fails to load them like in the snapshot.

Comment: could it be that the folder authorizations are working differently and I should add some CHMOD to the folders under 'static'?

Comment: 403 means there is a problem with permissions. You could try by adding `RUN chmod 755 /app/app` to your dockerfile. You can also check that from inside of k8s pod by `kubectl exec -it <pod_name> bash`. Remember to replace the old deployment when you change the image.

Comment: thank you, I can easily navigate in bash through those catalogs, i will try adding 755 :)

Comment: Check permissions on those catalogs and files.

Comment: Checked & changed the permissions and added a snapshot to the topic. From my point of view they are OK but same keeps happening... :(

Comment: might be because Kubernetes is using ingress for my service and path

Comment: You could try one more thing which is `allowPrivilegeEscalation: True`, you can read about it [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-the-security-context-for-a-container).